# Spinner (UIPickerView) or separate buttons to select quantity?

Tags: mobile, layout, ios

I am creating an iOS application for a stock picking system. Customers will order in stock and use this system to go and find the item off the shop floor to pack. They submit through the system and have to input the quantity to pick - but before A/B testing wanted to see if anyone else has experience of this problem before.

- Solution one - Select quantity via UIPickerView Spinner:

[image: select quantity]

[image: carousel]

Or

- Solution two - Buttons:

[image]

Have already looked at [Best way to select quantity of items for an eCommerce mobile application?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22230/best-way-to-select-quantity-of-items-for-an-ecommerce-mobile-application) but as this post is rather out of date, wanted to see what other opinions there were now, or any research into this topic.

If we implement the second style, we would also consider using swipe gestures to hide the 'None' and 'All' button, so users can just slide the buttons in and out of the screen, if the size of the buttons is an issue.

Comment: One potential issue is that the touch targets on the last two examples can be rather small.  Also, the "None" and "All" buttons if accidentally touched could cause the user to lose all the quantities they had built up so far...

Comment: So if we made the buttons higher, so they are a square shape, would you still be inclined to go for the buttons, or the spinner? Losing all the quantities could be a reason to add a swipe gesture to hide the buttons where they are not needed - didn't think of that.

Comment: The question that you linked has a very good answer about keyboard entry over spinners. I don't know why you think it's outdated. There are some patterns in UX that are 20-30 years old (Fitts' Law is 60).

Comment: Yes I know it's a good answer, just wanted to get some opinions to see whether as the OS has changed whether there would be any new information...especially as the swipe gestures button is a fairly new feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relation to your question, I think that the solution two its more right than first solution (maybe the buttons All and None, like landonz said, would be better delete it if it not are necessary or found other solution for that buttons) but it have keep in mind the colors of buttons.

There are accessibility guides for use colours in web applications (W3C) that would must be use in mobile application (I havent found for mobile apps exclusively). People with vision fault could have some issue for see correctly the buttons with those colours.

There are tools for measure the contrast and determine if colours they have enough or not. 
This is an example for check the contrast:
http://snook.ca/technical/colour_contrast/colour.html#fg=33FF33,bg=333333

I know that Im merging accesibility with usability but this is important although its something that not a lot of people keep in mind.

Comment: Accessibility is still a good angle to look at - definitely need to keep it in mind. Unfortunately the business I work for have recently included new branding guidelines, so colour variations are not much of an option. Shall have to try and work around that issue.